# Updating PHP Array without Client

Tags: php, arrays, graph, updating

I'm creating a statistics page which shows the daily user count of my network however I've ran into an issue. I'd like to update a PHP array every ~10 minutes with a new user count number. So once a client connects to the webpage it'll already contain a full, up to date, array of user counts to make a graph with.

How would I go along doing this?

Sincerely sorry if this isn't the right place to ask, first time using StackOverflow.

Comment: Use a cron job that runs every 10 minutes and updates a static file containing the statistics.

Comment: The file can be in JSON or `serialize()` format. When the user connects to the web page, it reads the file, calls `json_decode()` or `unserialize()` to convert it to an array, and formats the results.